# Notebook doesn't open

Tags: notebooks, crash, feyncalc

I have a notebook with my [program](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AojcPCtrHq_0hexcxq_KPYFr5OgBfw).
It works whit package FeynCalc. At the latter work with this document, I wrote the сode:

```
$LoadPhi = True;
$Configuration = "ChPTVirtualPhotons2" ;
$Lagrangians = "ChPTVirtualPhotons2"[2]
"ChPTVirtualPhotons2"[4] ;
Get["HighEnergyPhysics'FeynCalc'"] ;
Lagrangian[ChPTVirtualPhotons2[2]]
```

And next to ran the programs, but my program keeps crashing. Now ".nb file" with my program does't launch and crash.

So, how may I remove last changes?

Comment: you wrote `Get["HighEnergyPhysics'FeynCalc'"] ;`  But should not that be the back tick there instead? try with back ticks, not the straight up tick for context, and see what happens.

Comment: Maybe problem in this. But now I can not to open my program because of it crashes

Answer (score 2):

After following the instrunctions [here](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/Installation#dev_automatic_installation), e.g. by

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/master/install.m"]
InstallFeynCalc[InstallFeynCalcDevelopmentVersion -> True]
```

and running

```
$LoadPhi = True;
$Configuration = "ChPTVirtualPhotons2";
$Lagrangians = {ChPTVirtualPhotons2[2],
   ChPTVirtualPhotons2[4]};
Needs["FeynCalc`"]
Lagrangian[ChPTVirtualPhotons2[2]]
```

I get

[image]